# Does Facebook API allow me to publish a post to my personal page?

Tags: php, facebook

**Task:** Users must log in via Facebook OAuth and the application will be publishing a post using the current authorization and the Facebook API on users own feed.

**Question:** Is it possible using Facebook API to publish a post on my personal page (feed)? I have not found any endpoint which provides this functionality. And I also found that this may not be available from April 2018:

> As of April 24, 2018, the publish_actions permission has been removed. Please see Breaking Changes changelog for more details. To allow users of your application to share content with Facebook, we recommend that you use our products for sharing.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/user/feed)

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/page/feed#pubperms) you will need `publish_pages` permission to post as page from api v2.3 . Prior, it needed permission `publish_actions` in addition to manage_pages. Now they have introduced `publish_pages` specifically for that purpose.

Comment: I tried to use this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed&version=v3.3 to check. In `{page-id}` param I inserted `me` (that's as I understand will make the API use my own feed page) but I got the error _The field 'feed' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'user_posts' permission._.
Are you sure this endpoint can be used for publishing posts on my own feed page?

Comment: ahh ok take a look in the API post in the permission section maybe it solved by his selfe.

Comment: To say the /{user-id}/feed is outdated. you need to take a look in the breaking changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24 I don't know on what platform your webspace is runing so you need to take a looke for your selfe. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

No. As per the Facebook policy update. the user can't post on their profile(personal) feed via API.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/

Comment: `the user can post on their profile(personal) feed via API`. Can or can't?

Comment: Sorry, typo-mistake. Users cant post on their feed.